# How to implement cookiejar wtih http2

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, http2

I'm trying to make some http2 requests but I have no idea how to implement a cookie jar/container in node at all - not with standard http or http2. I've looked online but I've yet to find a solution. Say for example I want to make the following http2 request:

```
const client = http2.connect('https://twitter.com');
const req = client.request({':method': 'GET', ':path': '/' });
req.setEncoding("utf8");
var body = "";
req.on('response', (responseHeaders) => {

});
req.on('data', (chunk) => {
    body += chunk;
});
req.on('end', () =>{ 
    console.log(body);

    client.destroy();
});
```

how would I then go about handling cookies/sessions between subsequent requests. For example this request sets cookies in the response header. How would I carry those cookies on to the next request?

Answer (score 1):

Worked out a good solution. I can simply use the package `tough-cookie` and implement a function to store cookies as follows:

```
var cookiejar = new tough.CookieJar();

function storeCookies(responseHeaders, jar){
    responseHeaders['set-cookie'].forEach(function(value){
        jar.setCookie(value, "https://twitter.com/", function(){
        });
    });
};
```

then when issuing a request, I can set the cookie headers for that request by loading them into a string with `tough-cookie`:

```
var string = "";
cookiejar.getCookies('https://twitter.com/',function(err,cookies) {
   string = cookies.join('; ');
});
```

`tough-cookie` then automatically handles expiring and storing the cookies in a compliant fashion.